# legend box color changes if 2 legends in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I am trying to generate a ggplot based on the following df

```
df <- data.frame(
  Input = c("S1", "S2", "S3", "S4"),
  Brand = c("Brand01", "Brand01", "Brand01", "Brand01", "Brand02","Brand02","Brand02","Brand02"),
  Average = c(21.52027, 21.60699, 20.77871, 21.22759, 25.05574, 22.74372, 22.80795, 22.98509),
  Limit = c(31.89098, 31.89098, 31.89098, 31.89098, 31.57953, 31.57953, 31.57953, 31.57953))

p = ggplot(df, aes(x=Input, y=Average, fill=Brand)) +
       facet_wrap(~ Brand, ncol = 2) +
       geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge(), colour="black", width = 0.9, show.legend = FALSE) +
       xlab("Input") + ylab("Average") +
       theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size=14), axis.title.y = element_text(size=14),
             legend.text = element_text(size=14), plot.title = element_text(size = 20, face = "bold"),
             axis.text.x = element_text(size=6))+ 
       theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) +
       geom_hline(aes(yintercept=Limit, linetype = "dashed"), color = "red") +
       scale_linetype_manual(name = "Limit", values = "dashed", labels = "")
```

When `show.legend = FALSE` then the plot looks like that [image]
But when I have `show.legend = TRUE`
then the box of the Limit changes color, and I want to have it "grey" or white as in the first plot. [image] I tried some tips from other relevant topics, but nothing worked.

Answer (score 1):

Because you've declared `fill = Brand` at the main ggplot2 call, it is inherited by every layer. If you move it to the `geom_bar()` layer, the legend should display sensibly.

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
  Input = c("S1", "S2", "S3", "S4"),
  Brand = c("Brand01", "Brand01", "Brand01", "Brand01", "Brand02","Brand02","Brand02","Brand02"),
  Average = c(21.52027, 21.60699, 20.77871, 21.22759, 25.05574, 22.74372, 22.80795, 22.98509),
  Limit = c(31.89098, 31.89098, 31.89098, 31.89098, 31.57953, 31.57953, 31.57953, 31.57953))

ggplot(df, aes(x=Input, y=Average)) +
  facet_wrap(~ Brand, ncol = 2) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill=Brand), stat="identity", position=position_dodge(), colour="black", width = 0.9) +
  xlab("Input") + ylab("Average") +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size=14), axis.title.y = element_text(size=14),
        legend.text = element_text(size=14), plot.title = element_text(size = 20, face = "bold"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size=6))+ 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept=Limit, linetype = "dashed"), color = "red") +
  scale_linetype_manual(name = "Limit", values = "dashed", labels = "")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>